# Sending information in form using MAMP

Tags: javascript, php, http, post, mamp

I am following a tutorial and trying to send information in a form using MAMP because I need to simulate a client-server behaviour, and it's not working. I've copied the code from the tutorial, so there should be no errors in the code, but it's still not working.

What's supposed to happen: the contact information you type in the code should be sent to the server.

What actually happens: the information gets added to the URL. Also, the page refreshes even though I have used `preventDefault`.

Here is the code: 
**js:**

```
   const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        const message = {
            loading: 'img/form/spinner.svg',
            success: 'Спасибо! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся',
            failure: 'Что-то пошло не так...'
        };
    
        forms.forEach(item => {
            postData(item);
        });
    
        function postData(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
    
                let statusMessage = document.createElement('img');
                statusMessage.src = message.loading;
                statusMessage.style.cssText = `
                    display: block;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                `;
                form.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', statusMessage);
            
                const formData = new FormData(form);
    
                const object = {};
                formData.forEach(function(value, key){
                    object[key] = value;
                });
    
                fetch('server.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(object)
                }).then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    showThanksModal(message.success);
                    statusMessage.remove();
                }).catch(() => {
                    showThanksModal(message.failure);
                }).finally(() => {
                    form.reset();
                });
            });
        }
    
        function showThanksModal(message) {
            const prevModalDialog = document.querySelector('.modal__dialog');
    
            prevModalDialog.classList.add('hide');
            openModal();
    
            const thanksModal = document.createElement('div');
            thanksModal.classList.add('modal__dialog');
            thanksModal.innerHTML = `
                <div class="modal__content">
                    <div class="modal__close" data-close>×</div>
                    <div class="modal__title">${message}</div>
                </div>
            `;
            document.querySelector('.modal').append(thanksModal);
            setTimeout(() => {
                thanksModal.remove();
                prevModalDialog.classList.add('show');
                prevModalDialog.classList.remove('hide');
                closeModal();
            }, 4000);
        }
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$_POST = json_decode( file_get_contents("php://input"), true );
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

Can anybody please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: When does this JS code execute? Do the form elements you are trying to select in there, already exist at this point? Otherwise, `document.querySelectorAll('form')` might just have returned an empty list, and so you’d just be forEach-ing over nothing.

Comment: The JS code executes after the form has been created (it's at the end of my html file), so I don't think that's the problem. @CBroe

Comment: Did you debug to see if it actually goes into your submit handler function? Did you check the browser console for JavaScript errors? (Enable the “preserve log” option, so that it doesn’t get cleared when the form submit happens.)

Comment: @CBroe I've tried, there are no errors. And when I was trying to add a message after the eventListener, there was also nothing. It doesn't pick up the code and I can not understand why.

Comment: Add `console.log(forms.length)` after the first line you have shown above, and see if that gets a value > 0 to begin with.